# Saber quantos chips um dispositivo Android possui

Tags: android

Preciso saber se um dispositivo Android possui chip (SIM card) ou não. E caso possua, preciso saber se possui apenas um ou mais que 1.

Muito obrigado a todos que tentarem me ajudar.

Já pesquisei sobre essa dúvida mas não consegui respostas!

Answer (score 0):

Desde a API 22 você pode utilizar a função `getActiveSubscriptionInfoList ()`.

Ela retorna uma lista do tipo `SubscriptionInfo` de todos os SIMs inseridos no dispositivo. Verifique a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29).

Comment: Interessante, porém, estou trabalhando com a versão 4.0.3 do Android, ou seja, a partir da API 15. Mesmo assim, obrigado pela resposta @Vitor Henrique.

Comment: Até a API 22 o Android não suportava múltiplos SIMs, você pode testar as implementações contidas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim , mas não é garantia que funcionarão.

Comment: Muito obrigado Vitor Henrique!

Comment: Espero que tenha dado certo, marque como respondido se te ajudou, obrigado!